# td will not add horizontal scroll bar

Tags: css

I tried adding `overflow:auto;` and `overflow-x:auto;` to my `<table>` element and this still didn't work. Any ideas?

Here is my webpage:

http://www.whiterootmedia.com/database/dusty_arlia/jquery_cdns.html

Here is my code:

```
<table class="yellow_table"  style="overflow:auto; overflow-x:auto;">
<tr>
<th>Host</th>
<th>Location</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Google</td>
<td class="left_aligned_red_cell">https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>jQuery.com</td>
<td class="left_aligned_red_cell">http://code.jquery.com/</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Microsoft</td>
<td class="left_aligned_red_cell">http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#jQuery_Releases_on_the_CDN_0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>CDNJS</td>
<td class="left_aligned_red_cell">http://cdnjs.com/#jquery</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: give your table a width to go with the overflow:auto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the table in a div, and give `overflow:auto` to the div.